# Why firebase notifications are no longer working after upgrading iOS to10.3?

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, xcode7

Problem : I'm using firebase in my project, (using XCode 7), the push notifications used to work when I tested them in iOS 9.x, when I upgraded to iOS 10.3 and decided to work on notifications again, they don't show up on iPhone...

what I have checked :

> 1- firebase p12 certificates are valid
>
> 2- I have updated the pods for all firebase libs.
>
> 3- appdelegate setup is correct

I also have tried to push some messages using the firebase console, they were successful, but I received none.

[image: firebase]

in the firebase documentation, this is mentioned

> for devices running iOS 10 and above, you must assign your delegate
>   object to the UNUserNotificationCenter object to receive display
>   notifications, and the FIRMessaging object to receive data messages,
>   before your app finishes launching. For example, in an iOS app, you
>   must assign it in the applicationWillFinishLaunching: or
>   applicationDidFinishLaunching: method.

but the problem is in XCode 7, there's no `UNUserNotificationCenter`, so does that mean XCode 7 is no longer supported by firebase messaging?

**EDIT**

some friend says :

> hm i just tested from the console and it didn't work for me either

**EDIT2**

when I send from a php file to a single device, I get this reply in my php file

> {
>       "multicast_id": 6096716523074435565,
>       "success": 1,
>       "failure": 0,
>       "canonical_ids": 0,
>       "results": [
>           {
>               "message_id": "0:1492683303568634%84058575f9fd7ecd"
>           }
>       ] }

by the way, I get the token using this command

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution is to upgrade to XCode 8, due to the changes in push notifications in iOS 10.